# How do I hide/show html form fields (showing one output if the user says yes, and a different one if they say no)?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, web-development-server

I have started working on a web application where I am showing certain outputs depending on when the user says.  If they click the "no" button, I want the user to see one DIV, but if they select yes, a different DIV should be displayed.  I scripted the following code:

```
<style>
    #Question1 {
        width: 80%;
        padding: 15px 0;
        text-align: center;
        background-color: red;
        margin-top: 15px;
    }
</style>
<script>
<button id="no" onclick="myFunction()">No</button>
window.onload = function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("Question1").style.visibility = "hidden";
    document.getElementById("no").addEventListener("click", function myFunction() {
        var currentstate = document.getElementById("Question1").style.visibility;
        var newstate = currentstate == "visible" ? "hidden" : "visible"
        document.getElementById("Question1").style.visibility = newstate;

    });
}
```

After testing this code, I tried doing the same thing for "yes".  However, I found that when I did this, the "no" stopped working.

```
   <style>
#Question1 {
    width: 80%;
    padding: 15px 0;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: red;
    margin-top: 15px;
}
</style>
<style>
#Question2 {
 width: 80%;
 padding: 15px 0;
 text-align: center;
 background-color: blue;
 margin-top: 15px;
               }
</style>

<button id="yes" onclick="myFunction2()">Yes</button>

<button id="no" onclick="myFunction()">No</button>
<script>
window.onload = function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("Question1").style.visibility = "hidden";
    document.getElementById("no").addEventListener("click", function myFunction() {
        var currentstate = document.getElementById("Question1").style.visibility;
        var newstate = currentstate == "visible" ? "hidden" : "visible"
        document.getElementById("Question1").style.visibility = newstate;

    });
}


window.onload = function myFunction2() {
    document.getElementById("Question2").style.visibility = "hidden";
    document.getElementById("yes").addEventListener("click", function myFunction2() {
        var currentstate = document.getElementById("Question2").style.visibility;
        var newstate = currentstate == "visible" ? "hidden" : "visible"
        document.getElementById("Question2").style.visibility = newstate;

    });
}
```

How do I program hide/show functions for multiple buttons on one form?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I right understand you need to toggle questions depends on a button clicked. Here is my solution based on your code:

https://jsfiddle.net/75n60vtk/

```
<div id="Question1">Question1</div>
<div id="Question2">Question2</div>
<br>
<button id="yes">Yes</button>
<button id="no">No</button>
```

```
#Question1 {
  display: none;
  width: 80%;
  padding: 15px 0;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: red;
  margin-top: 15px;
}

#Question2 {
  display: none;
  width: 80%;
  padding: 15px 0;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: blue;
  margin-top: 15px;
}
```

```
document.getElementById("no").addEventListener("click", function() {
    document.getElementById("Question1").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("Question2").style.display = "block";
})

document.getElementById("yes").addEventListener("click", function() {
    document.getElementById("Question1").style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("Question2").style.display = "none";
})
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the quick response!  I tried the code out, and I was wondering - Is there a way to make the DIV show up below the buttons?

Comment: Yes, sure. Just change the HTML to

`<button id="yes">Yes</button>
<div id="Question1">Question1</div>

<button id="no">No</button>
<div id="Question2">Question2</div>`

Answer (score 0):

You're overriding the first window.onload function with the second one, and these functions don't need to be defined there. You can do simply:

```
<button id="yes" style="visibility: hidden" onclick="myFunction2()">Yes</button>
<button id="no"  style="visibility: hidden" onclick="myFunction()">No</button>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    var currentstate = document.getElementById("Question1").style.visibility;
    var newstate = currentstate == "visible" ? "hidden" : "visible"
    document.getElementById("Question1").style.visibility = newstate;
});

function myFunction2() {
    var currentstate = document.getElementById("Question2").style.visibility;
    var newstate = currentstate == "visible" ? "hidden" : "visible"
    document.getElementById("Question2").style.visibility = newstate;

});

function init() {
    document.getElementById("no").addEventListener("click", myFunction)
    document.getElementById("yes").addEventListener("click", myFunction2)
}

window.onLoad = init

</script>
```